# How can I Run Object detection on GPU?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, object-detection, yolo

This program is detecting the things from web cam but it's slow so how can i make it fast for better FPS and how can i use GPU for the faster detection and with better performance. And i how can i make it perfect .In this Program i have used the Yolo configuration and weights with coco dataset .

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov4-custom.cfg', 'yolov4.weights')

classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback.mp4')
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.2:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255,255,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what kind of gpu do you have?

Comment: i have nvidia 1650

Comment: you can set opencv dnn to CUDA backend, but you might have to compile opencv with cuda first. How fast is that gpu? Not sure whether it is worth the effort.

Comment: i have already done this thing but changes i need to make in the code to run on the gpu

Comment: what changes should i make to run the code on gpu

Comment: net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)

Comment: have a look at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/ for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Gpu we have to compile opencv and this can be done as follows in blog : https://haroonshakeel.medium.com/build-opencv-4-4-0-with-cuda-gpu-support-on-windows-10-without-tears-aa85d470bcd0

and after doing it add the two lines that will that will detect the Gpu and  program will run on GPU.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov4-custom.cfg', 'yolov4.weights')

classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()

# this below two line will help to run the detetection.
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)

net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback.mp4')
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.2:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255,255,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```